# Access Parent Entity in JPA Entity

Tags: java, jpa, struts2

Im using JPA 1, Struts2.3.1, Google-App-Enging 1.7.0

In my Comics I have property below with getter and setter:

```
@ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY, targetEntity=User.class)
private User user = null;
```

My method for JPA query:

```
public Comics readComics(int random, String url){
    EntityManager em = EMF.get().createEntityManager();
    Comics comics = null;

    try{
        Query q = em.createNamedQuery("Comics.getComics");
        q.setParameter("random", random);
        q.setParameter("url", url);
        comics = (Comics) q.getSingleResult();

    } catch(NoResultException ex){
        System.out.println("ERROR CATCHED: " + ex.getMessage());
        comics = null;
    } finally{
        em.close();
    }

    return comics;
}
```

In my view, I have:

```
<s:property value="comics.user.userName"/>
```

`userName` can't be accessed in that case, but when entity manager is not closed `userName` is displayed.

What would be the correct one? Is it okay to remove `em.close()`?

=======================

**Using `BeanUtils.copyProperties`**
I also tried code below:

```
Comics emComics = (Comics) q.getSingleResult();
BeanUtils.copyProperties(comics, emComics);
BeanUtils.copyProperties(comics.getUser(), emComics.getUser());
```

Is it the correct way of using `copyProperties`? Removing `BeanUtils.copyProperties(comics.getUser(), emComics.getUser());` will again not display the `user`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not ok to remove em.close() - if you do that you will end up with connection leaks. The application will stop working after all the connections in the pool are exhausted.

Simple fix is the make sure everything needed by the jsp in initialized before calling em.close().

If you are using hibernate as the provider then you can use Hibernate.initialize()

```
public Comics readComics(int random, String url){
    EntityManager em = EMF.get().createEntityManager();
    Comics comics = null;
   try{
        Query q = em.createNamedQuery("Comics.getComics");
        q.setParameter("random", random);
        q.setParameter("url", url);
        comics = (Comics) q.getSingleResult();

        Hibernate.initialize(comics.getUser());

    } catch(NoResultException ex){
        System.out.println("ERROR CATCHED: " + ex.getMessage());
        comics = null;
    } finally{
        em.close();
    }

    return comics;
}
```

If you are using some other provider you can look for an equivalent method or just write own function that just fetches one of the properties of the object to trigger the initialization of the proxy.

Another option is to modify the query using a join fetch to fetch the User association while fetching the comics.

The correct solution to this is to use either Spring or EJBs that provide solutions to easily deal with entity manager.  Your approach of opening a new entityManager for each query is not optimal - it should ideally be one entityManager per transaction or for the whole request.  Read up about lazy initialization exception, OpenSessionInViewFilter etc..

Comment: thanks. im using datanucleus. I can't use join since it is rectricted in Google-App-Engine.

Comment: yes, better to use something like dozer or BeanUtils. One problem you might run into is selecting which relations need to be copied - you might have to create different classes (VOs DTOs) for returning output that match the UI and then copy from the domain objects to those.

Comment: I edited the question showing the `BeanUtils.copyProperties`. Is that code ok?

Comment: That looks ok. BeanUtils.copyProperties only does a shallow copy, so you have explicitly have code to copy each of the associations that is required by the jsp. Dozer does a deep copy.  But in longer run shallow copy might work better as you have control in your code on what parts of the graph to materialize.